# How to style a pandas pivot table dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have created a pivot table dataframe and I want to add custom styling to it. I want to iterate over each row and column values and compare the data value from the previous column value. If the value is greater than the previous column value, change the background color to `'lightgreen'`. If the column value is less than the previous column value, change the background color to `'lightcoral'`. Please refer the image to take a look at the pivot table dataframe.[image]

```
df.columns

Index(['AUG-2022', 'SEP-2022', 'OCT-2022', 'NOV-2022', 'DEC-2022', 'JAN-2023'], dtype='object')
```

I tried this code to create a styler but I have been getting this error.

```
styler = df.style
# iterate over each row of the DataFrame
for i, row in enumerate(df.values):
    # iterate over each column of the row
    for j in range(1, len(row)):
            # compare current value to previous value
        if row[j] < row[j-1]:
#             # set background color to light red
            styler.set_properties(subset=[(i, j)], **{'background-color': 'lightcoral'})
        elif row[j] > row[j-1]:
#             # set background color to light green
            styler.set_properties(subset=[(i, j)], **{'background-color': 'lightgreen'})

styler
```

> raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")

I want to understand what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this.

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
def color(df):
    conds = [
        df.gt(df.shift(+1, axis=1)), #is the current column greater than the previous ?
        df.lt(df.shift(+1, axis=1)), #is the current column lower than the previous ?
    ]
    vals = [
        "background-color: lightgreen",
        "background-color: lightcoral",
    ]
    return pd.DataFrame(np.select(conds, vals, default=""),
                        index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

df.style.apply(color, axis=None)
```

Output :

[image]

*Input used :*

```
ms = pd.date_range(start="2023-01-01", end="2023-12-01", freq="MS").strftime("%b-%Y")

index = pd.Index([f"COMPANY_{i}" for i in range(1, 11)], name="COMPANY NAME")

columns = [m.upper() for m in ms]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.randint(low=0, high=10000, size=(len(index), len(columns))),
    index=index, columns=columns
)
```